# Why does my middle end node server stop running after I connect to a dabatase

Tags: mysql, node.js, api

Question: Why is my middle end server not responding after connecting to a database?

Hello, so I have a simple mysql database server running and open in mysql workbench (I ran a test and it is working), and I also have a simple middle end node app to handle and process requests. I can even run a query to make a database in mysql before the api stops responding.

The problem: after I connect to my database, my middle end end points stop working. such as my default page "/" for "hello world". I have very simple and basic node db connection code so I'm not sure why it's failing.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var https = require('https')
var mysql = require('mysql')
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(express.json())

var myLogger = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('LOGGED')
    next()
}
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    port: '3306',
    database:'mydbtest666'


});

db.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    db.destroy();
});
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!')
})


app.listen(5000)
```

I am using the logger to help log commands, and it will show that the endpoint was called, but no data is being shown on my screen and again the page just loads and loads.

I thought closing/destroying the connection would work, but it is not. Would a try catch change anything??

Here's another attempt with my signup but the middle end still freezes and with this attempt it no longer connects to the database:

```
app.post("/users/signup", (req, res) => {

    const username = req.body.username
    const password = req.body.password
    db.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected!");
        try {
            db.query("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?,?)", [username, password], (err, result) => { });
            db.destroy();
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });



});
```

Comment: Which part keep loading? Not the `Hello World!` page is it?

Comment: @tcadidot0 any endpoint does not load. the browser just loads and loads without displaying any data.

Comment: I usually experienced page keep loading when it doesn't know what to do next. I mean like normally when I do `db.query(..)` it always followed by `if(error)` but I didn't specify what to do if there's no error. Maybe you can provide the codes for the `/users/signup` page and I can try on that to see what's going on.

Comment: I did some quick testing on your second code and it seems like its fine until the variables definition but its stuck at loading when it gets to `db.connect` as I don't see the `console.log("Connected!")` being sent. May I know if there are any project you've done with similar style/type of codes and its working?

Comment: @tcadidot0 I unfortunately do not... I'm still absolutely stumped on this issue.. thank you for helping me so far.

Comment: May I suggest a different way to write the codes? It will be different from what you're currently doing though.

Comment: Thats what I have to do haha and am currently doing. will update. @tcadidot0